# Append Query String to main domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, query-string

I need to redirect/append (from .htaccess) query string to main domain
(e.g)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
.....
RewriteRule www.domain.com/?query=string [L,R=301]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below should work,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/?query=string [L,R=301]
```